# Rails app not showing notifications through ActionCable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I have a todo-list rails app that allow one user to mark others users public lists as their favorite. The goal here is: when the owner of the list create a new todo-item, the users which mark that same list as their favorite should receive a notification in real time without refreshing the page.

**app/assets/javascripts/channels/notification.js**

```
App.notifications = App.cable.subscriptions.create("NotificationsChannel", {
      connected: function() {
        // Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server
      },

      disconnected: function() {
        // Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server
      },

      received: function(data) {
        // Called when there's incoming data on the websocket for this channel
        $("#notifications").prepend(data.html);
      }
```

});

My div in **app/views/layouts/application.html.erb**

```
      <body>
          <div class="container">
          <div id="notifications">

          </div>
          <header>
            <div class="header_inner">
              <nav style="text-align: right;">
                <% if user_signed_in? %>
                  <%= link_to 'New Todo List', new_todo_list_path %> |
                  <%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
                <% else %>
                  <%= link_to "Log in", new_user_session_path %>
                <% end %>
              </nav>
            </div>
          </header>
          <%= yield %>
        </div>
      </body>
```

**app/models/notification.rb**

```
class Notification < ApplicationRecord
  after_create_commit { NotificationRelayJob.perform_later(self) }

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :recipient, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :notifiable, polymorphic: true
end
```

**app/models/todo_list.rb**

```
class TodoList < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :todo_items, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :favorites
  has_many :users, through: :favorites

  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :description, length: { maximum: 50 }

  def public?
    self.public
  end
end
```

**app/views/notifications/todo_lists/_created.html.erb**

```
<div><%= notification.user.email %> <%= notification.action %> new item!</div>
```

**app/channels/notifications_channel.rb**

```
class NotificationsChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "notifications:#{current_user.id}"
  end

  def unsubscribed
    stop_all_streams
  end
end
```

**app/jobs/notification_relay_job.rb**

```
  class NotificationRelayJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(notification)
    html = ApplicationController.render partial: "notifications/#{notification.notifiable_type.underscore.pluralize}/#{notification.action}", locals: {notification: notification}, formats: [:html]
    ActionCable.server.broadcast "notifications:#{notification.current_user}", html: html
  end
```

**app/controllers/todo_items_controller.rb**

```
class TodoItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_todo_list
  before_action :set_todo_item, except: [:create]

  def create
    @todo_item = @todo_list.todo_items.new(todo_item_params)
    if @todo_item.save
      @todo_list.users.each do |user|
        @noti = Notification.create(recipient: user, user: User.last, action: "create", notifiable: @todo_list)
      end
      redirect_to @todo_list, notice: 'Todo item added!'
    else
      redirect_to @todo_list, alert: 'Please some content in the new todo item'
    end
  end
  ...
```

**development.log**

```
web_1  | Finished "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 172.23.0.1 at 2018-04-17 00:58:28 +0000
web_1  | NotificationsChannel stopped streaming from notifications:2
web_1  | Started GET "/cable" for 172.23.0.1 at 2018-04-17 00:58:28 +0000
web_1  | Cannot render console from 172.23.0.1! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
web_1  | Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 172.23.0.1 at 2018-04-17 00:58:28 +0000
web_1  | Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
web_1  |   User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
web_1  | Registered connection (Z2lkOi8vZmFudGFzdGljLXN5c3RlbS9Vc2VyLzI)
web_1  | NotificationsChannel is transmitting the subscription confirmation
web_1  | NotificationsChannel is streaming from notifications:2
web_1  | Started POST "/todo_lists/3/todo_items" for 172.23.0.1 at 2018-04-17 00:58:31 +0000
web_1  | Cannot render console from 172.23.0.1! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
web_1  | Processing by TodoItemsController#create as HTML
web_1  |   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"WfKWJNbd0HiPj64/51vXsj7O/mJ7nF/U6tvwP5OQMsTLE0cgUQHXYq7D08bB3RUxuxqVTvcD6uGzWcNJqkxGQA==", "todo_item"=>{"content"=>"asd"}, "commit"=>"Create Todo item", "todo_list_id"=>"3"}
web_1  |   TodoList Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "todo_lists".* FROM "todo_lists" WHERE "todo_lists"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
web_1  |    (0.1ms)  begin transaction
web_1  |   SQL (2.2ms)  INSERT INTO "todo_items" ("content", "todo_list_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["content", "asd"], ["todo_list_id", 3], ["created_at", "2018-04-17 00:58:31.708390"], ["updated_at", "2018-04-17 00:58:31.708390"]]
web_1  |    (157.7ms)  commit transaction
web_1  |   User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "favorites" ON "users"."id" = "favorites"."user_id" WHERE "favorites"."todo_list_id" = ?  [["todo_list_id", 3]]
web_1  |   User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
web_1  |    (0.1ms)  begin transaction
web_1  |   SQL (1.5ms)  INSERT INTO "notifications" ("user_id", "recipient_id", "action", "notifiable_type", "notifiable_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["user_id", 3], ["recipient_id", 1], ["action", "followed"], ["notifiable_type", "TodoList"], ["notifiable_id", 3], ["created_at", "2018-04-17 00:58:31.915523"], ["updated_at", "2018-04-17 00:58:31.915523"]]
web_1  |    (97.2ms)  commit transaction
web_1  | [ActiveJob] Enqueued NotificationRelayJob (Job ID: a32e8a9d-d9fd-4a1c-90c1-891c48709b4b) to Async(default) with arguments: #<GlobalID:0x00007f651054f610 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://fantastic-system/Notification/72>>
web_1  | Redirected to http://localhost:3000/todo_lists/3
web_1  |   Notification Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "notifications".* FROM "notifications" WHERE "notifications"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 72], ["LIMIT", 1]]
web_1  | Completed 302 Found in 359ms (ActiveRecord: 261.1ms)
web_1  | 
web_1  | 
web_1  | [ActiveJob] [NotificationRelayJob] [a32e8a9d-d9fd-4a1c-90c1-891c48709b4b] Performing NotificationRelayJob (Job ID: a32e8a9d-d9fd-4a1c-90c1-891c48709b4b) from Async(default) with arguments: #<GlobalID:0x00007f64cc04ab18 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://fantastic-system/Notification/72>>
web_1  | [ActiveJob] [NotificationRelayJob] [a32e8a9d-d9fd-4a1c-90c1-891c48709b4b]   User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
web_1  | [ActiveJob] [NotificationRelayJob] [a32e8a9d-d9fd-4a1c-90c1-891c48709b4b]   Rendered notifications/todo_lists/_followed.html.erb (4.9ms)
web_1  | [ActiveJob] [NotificationRelayJob] [a32e8a9d-d9fd-4a1c-90c1-891c48709b4b] [ActionCable] Broadcasting to notifications:3: {:html=>"<div>a@a.com.br followed you!</div>\n"}
web_1  | [ActiveJob] [NotificationRelayJob] [a32e8a9d-d9fd-4a1c-90c1-891c48709b4b] Performed NotificationRelayJob (Job ID: a32e8a9d-d9fd-4a1c-90c1-891c48709b4b) from Async(default) in 7.58ms
web_1  | Started GET "/todo_lists/3" for 172.23.0.1 at 2018-04-17 00:58:32 +0000
web_1  | Cannot render console from 172.23.0.1! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
web_1  | Processing by TodoListsController#show as HTML
web_1  |   Parameters: {"id"=>"3"}
web_1  |   TodoList Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "todo_lists".* FROM "todo_lists" WHERE "todo_lists"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
web_1  |   Rendering todo_lists/show.html.erb within layouts/application
web_1  |   TodoItem Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "todo_items".* FROM "todo_items" WHERE "todo_items"."todo_list_id" = ?  [["todo_list_id", 3]]
web_1  |   User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
web_1  |   User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
web_1  |   Rendered collection of todo_items/_todo_item.html.erb [4 times] (7.3ms)
web_1  |   Rendered todo_items/_form.html.erb (2.8ms)
web_1  |   Rendered todo_lists/show.html.erb within layouts/application (16.8ms)
web_1  | Completed 200 OK in 47ms (Views: 44.4ms | ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)
web_1  | 
web_1  | 
web_1  | Finished "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 172.23.0.1 at 2018-04-17 00:58:32 +0000
web_1  | NotificationsChannel stopped streaming from notifications:2
web_1  | Started GET "/cable" for 172.23.0.1 at 2018-04-17 00:58:32 +0000
web_1  | Cannot render console from 172.23.0.1! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
web_1  | Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 172.23.0.1 at 2018-04-17 00:58:32 +0000
web_1  | Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
web_1  |   User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
web_1  | Registered connection (Z2lkOi8vZmFudGFzdGljLXN5c3RlbS9Vc2VyLzI)
web_1  | NotificationsChannel is transmitting the subscription confirmation
web_1  | NotificationsChannel is streaming from notifications:2
```

I'm able to see all user that favorite a list through "@todo_list.users"(that will receive the notification), the console says that NotificationChannel is trasmitting and streaming, but nothing happens when I create a new todo item. I've been searching it for a while but it seens I not quite understand ActionCable very well :(.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially, the problem is who do you send your notification. You especified to notifications.current_user and it must be send to notification.recipient_id

in **app/jobs/notification_relay_job.rb**

Change the code

```
ActionCable.server.broadcast "notifications:#{notification.current_user}", html: html
```

to

```
ActionCable.server.broadcast "notifications:#{notification.recipient_id}", html: html
```

After do this, make login in sender and recipient users, create the  notification and test it again.

Comment: That's it! Works like a charm! Just instead "notifications:#{notification.recipient_user}" I used "notifications:#{notification.recipient_id}". Thanks for helping, bro.